# Can't disable angular animation

Tags: angular, animation

I have an animation that make an item in a liste slide on the right and go away.

```js
export const flyOut = trigger('flyOut', [
  transition(':leave', [
    animate(300, style({
      transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
    })),
  ])
]);
```

I want to disable it conditionally, but i can't event to disable it.

on my component i do this, after injecting in `@Component` decorator the   `animations: [flyOut]`

```html
  <my-component *ngFor="let element of myObservable$ | async"
                @flyOut
                [@.disabled]="true"
      ></my-component>
```

The annimation won't disable.
I've tried to put it on a div, use the parent, to use hostBiding etc ...
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the [@.disabled]="true" in the parent div and @flyOut animation in child div

```
   <div [@.disabled]="true"> 
    <my-component @flyOut>
    </my-component>
   </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but not succeded, maybe my animation is incorrect ?